# Trouble with connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I've trouble with connection to database MySQL. I wrote a console project with databese and I had a class `ConnectionManager` here. Now I'm starting writing site. I want connect database ang just copy my working class`ConnectionManager` into new dynamic project. But this class return NULL instead of connection. Maybe you know  where is problem.
Thank you in advance!
[image]
Connector is added. NullPointer exception was called by  `Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();`

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class ConnectionManager {
private static String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registration";

private static String user = "root";
private static String password = "root";
private static Connection connection = null;

public static Connection getConnection()
{
    if (connection == null)
    {
        initializeConnection();
    }
    return connection;
}

private static void initializeConnection()
{
    Connection conn;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,password);
        connection = conn;// doesn't execute and I don't know why
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Using: `Connection conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();`

Comment: Do you get a stack trace printed to console?

Comment: yes, I debug it. And `conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,password);` execute and after go to `catch`

Comment: Probably the line conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl,user,password); is throwning an exception. Look that.

Comment: Probably, your user does not have privileges. Try to access via mysql console to your mysql server from where you are going to execute a code.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the constructor and add your code in that. I'm doing exact same thing and its working. Like this:-

```
    public Connection()  {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    try {
        if (connection == null)
        {
            initializeConnection();
        }
       return connection;       
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably more than one reason

1- check your user permission

```
GRANT [type of permission] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';
```

2- check your jdbc url and its port. Make sure 3306 port is avaible to using mysql

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registration
```

3- check your jar file

- Download .jar file(mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar) and move it to libs folder
- Right click your project > properties > Libraries > ADD jar/Folder Select your jar file in that folder.

Test your connection

```
String dbUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javabase";
String username = "root";
String password = "root";

try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password)) {
    System.out.println("Connected to DB!");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Error: ", e);
}
```

4- check your user password.
if you not sure change your password.

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');
```